# Accessing WCF application through Service Fabric reverse proxy

Tags: c#, wcf, azure-service-fabric

We've made a a WCF application that we're hosting inside an On-Premise Service fabric cluster. Accessing it through the Service Fabric reverse proxy is giving us some difficulties.

Our cluster has 3 nodes(*eg. 10.0.0.1-3*) and the application should be accessible through the reverse proxy (*listening on port 19081*) on every node. Unfortunatly it only works through the SF reverse proxy on the node hosting the WCF application(*also listening on port 19081*). Accessing it through the other nodes results in a *400 bad request*.

If we run the WCF service on a different port, we can access it directly / locally, but not through the Service Fabric Reverse Proxy.

We're running multiple ASP.NET Core/REST services on the cluster and these work fine.

**Example**

If the service is running on the 10.0.0.1 node we can access it through:
http://10.0.0.1:19081/myserviceType/soaphost/myservice.svc

However these URL's result in a *400 bad request* status code:
http://10.0.0.2:19081/myserviceType/soaphost/myservice.svc
http://10.0.0.3:19081/myserviceType/soaphost/myservice.svc

**Code example**

We're using the following code to create the WCF Service Instance Listener:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[] {
        CreateWcfListener("ServiceEndpoint",  serviceProvider.GetService<ServiceType>())
    };
}

private ServiceInstanceListener CreateWcfListener<T>(string endpoint, T serviceImplementation)
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener((context) =>
    {
        var endpointConfig = context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint(endpoint);
        int port = endpointConfig.Port;
        string scheme = endpointConfig.Protocol.ToString();
        string host = context.NodeContext.IPAddressOrFQDN;
        string uriStem = endpointConfig.PathSuffix;
        string uri = $"{scheme}://{host}:19081{context.ServiceName.AbsolutePath}/{uriStem}";
        CustomBinding listenerBinding = CreateListenerBinding();
        WcfCommunicationListener<T> listener = new WcfCommunicationListener<T>(
            wcfServiceObject: serviceImplementation,
            serviceContext: context,
            address: new EndpointAddress(uri),
            listenerBinding: listenerBinding);
        return listener;
    }, endpoint);
}
```

We would like to know why it doesn't work, but more importantly how to fix it.

Comment: At what port is your Reverse Proxy listening? You're hosting the WCF service at port 19081 (which may be the same port your Reverse Proxy is listening at). Try to host the WCF service itself on a different port than the Reverse Proxy

Comment: Our Reverse Proxy is listening on port 19081. If we host the WCF service on a different port, we can access that WCF service directly, but not through the Service Fabric Reverse Proxy. (_I have also added some clarification to the question_)